Inner product in extended Hilbert space $\mathcal{R}+\mathcal{T}$
The extended Hilbert space is defined as $\mathcal{R}+\mathcal{T}$ such that it consists of normalizable periodic functions $u(r, t+T)=u(r,t)$. The inner product in this space is defined as:
$$
((u,v))=\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} dt\int dr \, u^*(r,t)v(r,t)
$$
The usual inner product is:
$$
(u,v)=\int dr \, u^*(r,t)v(r,t)
$$
Now define an operator in the extend Hilbert space as
$$
\mathcal{H}=H-i\hbar\partial_t
$$
where $H(t+T)=H(t)$.
Suppose $u_m$ and $u_n$ are eigenstates of it, such that
$$
\mathcal{H} u_m = E_m u_m,\quad \mathcal{H} u_n = E_n u_n
$$
and $-\hbar\omega/2\le E_m, E_n < \hbar\omega/2$, with $\omega=2\pi/T$. From Floquet theorem $u_m$ and $u_n$ are also periodic in $t$.
Show that
$$
(u_m, u_n)=((u_m,u_n))
$$
This is basically the claim in this paper and I have just outline the main ingredients above. I cannot understand this claim since it is obvious that $(u_m, u_n)$ is a periodic function in $t$, while $((u_m, u_n))$ is a constant. I don't know if this is a false claim or have a deeper meaning that I haven't understood?

I don't understand the notation in this question - what are $\mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{T}$, and what operation is the $+$ between them? The usual space of wavefunctions would be some $R = L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and if you want to extend this to a space of functions of space and time, the correct operation would be the tensor product $R\otimes T$ with some space of periodic functions $T = L^2([-T/2,T/2])$. I can't make sense of what the $+$ is supposed to mean.

@ACuriousMind I just copy the notation in the paper. I think the meaning is what you described.
